# Is there a way to retrieve the SQL results without using iterator? (JAVA and hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

From what I've seen, I need to use `Iterator` to access the SQL search results from Hibernate.

But if I only have a single record result, for example:

```
 select * from customers where id = 1;
```

Is there a way of avoid using an Iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate always return List so for single row you can get it by using index

ListName.get(0);
 Or 
 you can use 'uniqueResult();'

Answer (score 0):

try [org.hibernate.Query#uniqueResult()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html), but ensure its only `one` or `none` record return.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uniqueResult()`. This will return a single object (an exception will be thrown if moret than one found.

Example:

```
String hql = "from User user where user.id = 1";
User user = (User) session.createQuery(hql).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `HQL` instead of `SQL` if you're using `Hibernate`.

An `HQL` query would be:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User user where user.id = :id");
query.setParameter("id", 1);
return (User) query.uniqueResult();
```

Another way would be using the `Criteria` API of `Hibernate`, so the query would be:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1));
return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
```