# Is there a way to retrieve the SQL results without using iterator? (using hibernate)

Tags: hibernate

I have an HQL that returns multiple records.

e.g.

```
select * from employees where surname like 'A%' order by employee_id
```

How can I access the 3rd field in the 3rd record without iterating through the list? I've searched the net but came away empty-handed.

I know about the get function but the list is a list of Objects (i.e. not a specific class) so I **cannot** use something like:

```
myList.get(2).getSurname();
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve the SQL results without using iterator? (JAVA and hibernate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209613/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-sql-results-without-using-iterator-java-and-hib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a List, then you get the third item from it with [`list.get(2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29), like anywhere. If you did something like [`Query.iterate()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Query.html#iterate%28%29), then you've purposely asked for the result to be loaded on demand instead of all up front, and you're stuck with the consequences of doing so. If you have a problem with calling [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) a few times, then fix the `order by` clause of your query to put that record first. Otherwise use `Query.list()` instead, which loads the entire result of your query into memory at once as  a List.

As for the third field, when you use HQL, you're loading objects, not fields, so it doesn't really make any sense to talk about fields in that way.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I know about get but I am unsure on how to get the 3rd field. the list is a list of objects. not any particular class. so I cannot using the get functions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a `List<Object[]>` if it's not a specific type? In that case, you want list.get(2)[2]